# Alternative for PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to use one of the newest versions of Python, (3.5+), and I need to import Image. I use:

> from PIL import Image

except this returns an error. I don't have the error on my right now but the important part is there is a problem with PIL (I have already determined that from my Python Discord server)

Can I use pillow? I think I have that installed. I would try it but I want to know how (and if) it's applicable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use pillow?

Sure. `pillow` is a successor project of `PIL`, as development on the latter was last continued [in 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315041249/http://hg.effbot.org/pil-2009-raclette).

The [first thing mentioned](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html) in the official `pillow` documentation is how to import the `Image` class.

Comment: Hi man, thank you for helping. In the link you posted, the code still says "PIL", shouldn't it say pillow? I am a bit confused.

Comment: `pillow` is a direct fork of the old `PIL` project and therefore uses the old modules names. Go ahead and have a look [at the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/index.html).

Comment: Try PILasOPENCV - this library only needs numpy and opencv for the same function calls as PIL, more info at https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV